# How to move the text to the right when the amount of letters or numbers increase

Tags: html, css, text, move

I´m creating a game hud with a money display. So let´s say the Player has 0 Dollar in his pocket it should look like this:

[image]

Note: That´s in the upper right corner

Position of the Text:

```
right: 12.00vw;
top: 1.7vw;
```

Now let´s be unrealistic and say the Player has 50.000.000 Dollar ins his pocket it i´ll look like this: [image]

But it should look like this:

[image]

So how can i let the text move to the right instead of to the left when the number of money in the pocket increases?

Code:

```
<div class="moneyhud"></div>
    <div ID="hud">
        <div id="top">
        <span id="text4">50000000 $</span>  <!-- Money -->      
    </div>
 </div>

#text4 {
    font-size: 1.5vw;
    color: rgb(53, 143, 73);
    position: absolute;
    right: 12.00vw;
    top: 1.7vw;
    text-shadow: 4px 4px 10px #313131;
}

.moneyhud {
    position: absolute;
    background-image: 
    url("https://img.rehmann.online/a/fastlife/gruengeld.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    right: 1.00vw;
    top: 2vw;
    z-index: -1;
    height: 30px;
    width: 288px;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using the CSS property `text-align`?

Comment: You should be using a flexbox. Set the container of the text to display flex, then make the text element flex grow. From there, on the parent element, you can align the text to the right.

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette i added the code to the post

Comment: @Kwright02 how exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
#text4 {
    font-size: 1.5vw;
    color: rgb(53, 143, 73);
    position: absolute;
    right: 12.00vw;
    top: 1.7vw;
    text-shadow: 4px 4px 10px #313131;
}

.moneyhud {
    position: absolute;
    background-image: 
    url("https://img.rehmann.online/a/fastlife/gruengeld.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    right: 1.00vw;
    top: 2vw;
    z-index: -1;
    height: 30px;
    width: 288px;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="moneyhud">
    <div id="hud">
        <div id="top">
          <span id="text4">50000000 $</span>  <!-- Money -->  
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

That is the code you currently have. Notice how you're relying on hard-coded values to display dynamic content. Try something like this:

```css
#text4 {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: rgb(53, 143, 73);
    text-shadow: 4px 4px 10px #313131;
}


.moneyhud {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 10px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 288px;
    background-image: 
    url("https://img.rehmann.online/a/fastlife/gruengeld.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="moneyhud">
    <span id="text4">50000000 $</span> 
 </div>
```

This should give you a rough idea of how to flex-box it

Comment: Thanks! I aligned it to the left by editing the justify-content to:    

 justify-content: space-between; and then added a margin to the text: margin-left: 2vw;